# How do I find out which processes in the task manager are useless?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

My Task Manager looks like this:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/50525207@N02/4967509129/sizes/l/in/photostream/

All I want to do is work in Visual Studio. Which processes can I safely end?

Also I noticed MANY instances of svchost.exe process. I know these are service hosts or something but is it normal to have these many instances? Could it be a virus?

Oh and sometimes when I try to kill a process, it JUST won't end; like I would click "End Process Tree" but it still keeps on running!

How do you REALLY kill a process?

So to sum up, I basically want to know what processes can I kill safely so my PC doesn't hang when running Visual Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a strong development machine to run a behemoth like Visual Studio 2010.

It would help to have your computer's specs, such as computer model, RAM and disk models (and age).
However, it's entirely possible that your computer is simply not strong enough.

In any case, do not blindly kill running processes, since this can cause bad problems.

Comment: It's Windows XP Professional OS in my PC . It says Intel (R), Pentium (R) D CPU 3.00 GHz, 3.01 GHz,504 MB of RAM..what else do I need to tell ?

Comment: How old is this computer ? What model is the hard disk?

Comment: Its 3 years old HCL Flatron PC

Comment: The CPU seems good enough for VS2010. Regarding RAM: Could you please post a screenshot of the Performance tab in Task Manager? The disk model can be found in Disk Manager right-click context-menu and Properties and Hardware tab.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the list of processes, I'm not sure that your problem is related to the # of processes on the machine - I don't see anything unreasonable in that list.

It also appears that you've only got 1G of RAM in the machine, it's possible that it'll run faster with more RAM (but that's not clear because it appears that there's plenty of RAM to spare (you have 512M commited out of 1.2G of available commit).

My guess is that the reason that visual studio is running slowly because it's hitting the disks a lot (but obviously I can't tell for sure).  Have you looked at the disk resources in the resource manager to see what's using your hard disk resources?

Comment: Where is Resource Manager?

Comment: Also what's this figure about how much RAM is committed ? what does it even mean ? How to utilize more of this RAM so my PC isn't slow ? especially when running VS..plz help

Comment: I googled about Windows resource manager. I don't think it's there in Windows XP OS..the one I am using. How do i check now ? Any other tool for that ?

Comment: @Tofystedeth :: I am a girl :|  ...yeah I too thot I need to upgrade RAM..will do so..thnx all for answering

Comment: Actually, she has half a gig. That plus the typical 1.5 x RAM for a pagefile makes what you see in the Task Manager view there. I wouldn't like to run anything relatively modern on just half a gig of RAM, much less Visual Studio. I'd definitely suggest to add more RAM to the system. - edit: Apologies happysoul.

Answer (score 2):

[Black Viper's site](http://www.blackviper.com/) is the go-to site for Windows services, including recommendations on which services can be stopped and the possible consequences, and suggested sets of services to enable depending on how you use your machine.